# Data type models c++

Tags: c++, types, architecture

everyone. I have just started learning C++ and programming, and my exam task is about:

What does 'data type model' means? What kinds of 'data type models' do you know?

Actually, I can't find anything about it on the Web :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: table of different data types]

There are many data types in c++:

- int :integer numbers
- double :real number
- float: numbers with floating points
- string : texts
- char : characters

You can learn the details (and see where I got the image from) by visiting this website:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types